# How do you pause between actions with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, selenium, ui-automation

I've read all of the "why would you want to do that" answers, and the "don't do that, do this" answers. I agree that pausing along the way in automated tests makes no sense unless you are actually waiting for a condition to arrive.

That said, there are times I want to 'step through' a list of actions without breakpoints to see the test run smoothly without interruption, during development. Also, stepping through breakpoints sometimes total breaks tests. So here is the scenario: I have hidden menus that show when hovering over them, and then when you hover over the now-visible options they are highlighted by changing their background colors as the mouse moves from one to another; common menu scenario. I want to automate that very thing and be able to see it work WHILE I'M DEVELOPING IT, and then throw that part away when I like what I see. Pardon me, I'm not shouting, just emphasizing.

So I get the top element of the menu, then the list of options to chose from. Then hover over each of the first 3 options in order.

```
var element = page.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("actions"));
var elementLi = element.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

Actions action = new Actions(page.WebDriver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
action.MoveToElement(elementLi[1]).Build().Perform();
action.MoveToElement(elementLi[2]).Build().Perform();
action.MoveToElement(elementLi[3]).Build().Perform();
```

Yes I can set breakpoints, but if I put implicit waits, or Thread.Sleep(5000) in between each of the MoveToElement calls there is no pause. I.E., it runs through lickity-split without so much as a wink at me for good-neighborliness.

This is hardly a critical issue, I agree. But why does nothing work to pause between?

Comment: I actually did something very similar when I wanted to check the colour change of elements when mouse-occurs. I'm surprised to see that sleeping isn't helping. I appreciate that you're looking for the 'not ideal but suitable answer' for the time being before scrapping it and doing it 'properly'. As such, have you tried instantiating a new `Actions()`, doing the moveTo, sleep, new actions, moveTo, sleep, etc ?

Comment: love the use of "lickity-split"

Comment: I reached this thread searching for pause() method of the Actions class and thought maybe we can use pause() method in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pause` between actions

```
(new Actions(driver))
.clickAndHold(car1)
.moveToElement(car2Tail)
.pause(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.release(car1).build()
.perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people use a `FluentWait` , such as `WebDriverWait`  to wait for a element to appear before continuing.  Lots of examples on this website and all over the internet.  Just make a method called `waitForElementToAppear( By locator )`  and then fill it out with your implementation.

Comment: Clearly you didn't read or understand my question. Normally one would do exactly this, but that is not what I am trying to do in development. That is what I do when I am writing the finished test case and need it to do that very thing.

Answer (score 1):

In my java automation framework, I use the WebDriver$Timeouts.class interface - implicitlyWait(long time, TimeUnit unit)method.

```
webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This method specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if this is not immediately present.

I'm quite sure you'll find something that would suite your code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I used, except it didn't work, as I said in my post. I only spent hours and hours on it though ;-)
I was really surprised that it didn't work, nor did Thread.Sleep. It's like there is something about the Actions collection that works differently.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to want something that will pause when not actually waiting for something, I suspect what should work is to use a `FluentWait` such as `WebDriverWait` (as noted in another answer), but tell it to wait for a condition you know isn't going to happen and catch and ignore the `TimeoutException`.

Something along the lines of

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds, sleepInMilliseconds);
    wait.until(Predicates.<WebDriver> alwaysFalse());
}
catch(TimeoutException e) {
    //Ignore the timeout.  It's what we *want* to happen.
}
```

using the overload of the `WebDriverWait` [`until`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) that takes a guava predicate.

You'll want to minimize polls of the condition with an appropriate choice of the sleep period.

Comment: That is an intriguing idea. I shall try it. BTW, what is a guava predicate?
Ah, Java stuff.

Comment: Guava is an open-source collections and functional programming library from Google, which is already used by Selenium.  And I've now implemented and tested this code, and it indeed works.

Comment: Just noticed you're doing this for asp.net, so probably not using Java.  Something similar should work in any language though.